# finite subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory

which group is infinite but all of its subgroups are finite?

Comment: If you mean "proper subgroup" then see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group

Comment: There are much easier examples than Tarski Monsters! For example, fix a prime $p$, and take the multiplicative group of complex $p^n$-th roots of unity for all $n \ge 0$.

Comment: Of course, the group mentioned by Derek is just the Prufer group.

Answer (score 3):

Yes but the Tarski monsters were the first known finitely generated examples. It is
open whether there exist finitely presented groups with this property.

Comment: As an elaboration to Jack's answer, see some of the remarks here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/78410/finitely-presented-infinite-group-with-no-element-of-infinite-order

Comment: Yes but there was no request for a finitely generated example! I suspect that you are just trying to make an easy question more interesting (which is of course not unreasonable)!